# easily change month and year in calendar in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use calendar to select a date, but it takes time when I have to pick another month or year, because I can only pick another month by clicking prev or next month one by one, is there any other way to make it easier to select a month or a year? maybe something like dropdownist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most people use a javascript library for a responsive calendar control allowing you to quickly select a month/year.

Two possibilities include:

- Microsoft's [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).  Note that in the sample you can click the Month/Year header to quickly select a different month or year.

or

- [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year) with Month/Year dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a dropdownlist, you have to build it yourself. Do take note of the Leap Year [**algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).